# Is it possible to bind scapy to any port to recieve packet?

Tags: tcp, scapy, packet-sniffers

Say I want scapy to be a server to receive packet,
like:

```
>> p=r("host:port") // waiting for a package
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to *bind* a socket, you'll have to use the `socket` module from Python. You can do so from Scapy and use it to dissect the captured packet.

By doing so however, you'll behave as a regular application and hence will only get the "application" layer (and not the network layers `IP` and `TCP` or `UDP`.

Now if you want to capture one packet from the network on a specific port, you can do so in "pure" Scapy, with the `sniff()` function and a simple BPF filter:

```
p = sniff(filter="port 53", count=1)[0]
```